# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to datatype int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this two stored procedure that return data:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spBuscarUrl]
@CodigoContrato nvarchar(255),  
@url nvarchar(255) OUTPUT  
AS    

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT @url = url  
    FROM v_compras_y_contrataciones AS cc  
    WHERE CodigoContrato = @CodigoContrato;  
RETURN
```

When I'm trying to return the value for the second stored procedure, the error says:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spCaller]
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @URL nvarchar(255);  
EXECUTE spBuscarUrl  
    'MIREX-2017-00001', @url = @URL OUTPUT;  
RETURN convert(nvarchar(255),@URL);  
END
```

**Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCaller, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do//Public/Tendering/OpportunityDetail/Index?noticeUID=DO1.NTC.2' to data type int.**

Comment: What is the point of this procedure? It isn't doing anything except calling another procedure. Why not just call spBuscarUrl?

Comment: What i want is to only display the url and not to fill. That's why I have two sp. @SeanLange

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line in `spCaller`:

```
RETURN convert(nvarchar(255),@URL);
```

The `RETURN` statement can only return `INT`, not `NVARCHAR`. If you want to return anything from a Stored Produre that is not an INT you need to either use an output parameter or `SELECT`.

Comment: using the select at the end works fine, but can i call the return value using asp net code? @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: Of course you can - the same way you get data from any other SQL call in .NET. All you need to do is create an `SqlCommand`, set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` and the `CommandText` to the *name* of the stored procedure. You can then use `ExecuteScalar` if you only want the first value of the first record (which is the way to go in your case).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value, use a function.  In this case, though, you can't do that because of the `execute`.  So use an output parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[spCaller] (
    out_url nvarchar(255) output
) AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE spBuscarUrl 'MIREX-2017-00001', @url = @out_URL OUTPUT;  
END;
```

Based on your `execute` statement, you seem to know how to call such a stored procedure.